# inverting sign of a variable in R

Tags: r, database, dataframe, sign

I want to flip the sign of a column. I have data like this:

```
id    var_x
1       19
2       -4
3       3 
4       -1
```

I want to simply flip the signs of those variables:

```
id    var_x   var_x_1
1       19     -19
2       -4      4
3       3      -3
4       -1      1
```

I've tried this, but it's not working. Any advice to get this to work?

```
df$var_x_1 <- invert_variable(df$var_x)
head(cog$TRBTS_m1_inverted)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can multiply by `-1` so that `-1` times negative value returns positive, on positive value returns negative and on 0 as 0

```
df$var_x_1 <- -1 * df$var_x
```

-output

```
df
  id var_x var_x_1
1  1    19     -19
2  2    -4       4
3  3     3      -3
4  4    -1       1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:4, var_x = c(19L, -4L, 3L, -1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```